# What are some Physical Mailing Services with APIs? (pdf to delivered letter)

Tags: automation, usps

I'm writing a bill generation service for a client, and I would like to program my self out of the most time consuming part of the process. It goes something like this.

> print X number of pdfs and envelopes, stuff envelops, stamp, and bring to post office

It would only be a few hundred bills monthly to start but it could grow. I'm sure some sort of service exists that provides an api to deliver a printed pdf to an address but I can't find one. I think part of my problem is discovering the terminology to google with.

Have you ever used any services like this?

**UPDATE**
I've found some helpful search terms, but no good results yet.

> Mail Processing Services
>   Document Processing Services

I should also add that I'm located in nyc and am looking for a US based solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any service that allows you to send letters via snail mail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223730/is-there-any-service-that-allows-you-to-send-letters-via-snail-mail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [PostalMethods Web-to-Postal](http://www.postalmethods.com/). PostalMethods offers a SOAP Web Service where you can provide a letter document and a postal address - we take care of the rest.

Our [Postal API](http://www.postalmethods.com/postal-api) section containing all the data you need to quickly send letters and postcards directly from any application. The [Reference Manual](http://www.postalmethods.com/resources/reference) of our SOAP Web Service API and many [Code Samples](http://www.postalmethods.com/resources/samples) will help send your snail mail quickly.

We also offer a free development account and free, quick and unlimited support. Pricing model is pay-as-you-go. Purchase a prepaid card from $10 to $10,000 and enjoy volume discounts.

Comment: (it's 2017 and) PostalMethods doesn't integrate with Zapier

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in such things, but it sounds like you're looking for something like this: http://www.billingpros.com/

For what it's worth, the magic Google keywords I used were "[automatic postal billing](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=automatic%20postal%20billing&btnG=Google+Search&meta=)". ;)

Comment: They're a little behind the times - judging by their expert "ebilling" solution, I may need to look elsewhere. http://www.billingpros.com/ViewEBill.htm

Answer (score 0):

I found a local shipping center who will receive pdf's via email and send them out and bill me for a negotiated nominal fee. A service with an api doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

We were investigating Lob's services. However, Lob required both the recipient's and the sender's address while we only had the former at our disposal.
Therefore, we did not choose Lob.